# nuget pack produces unwanted content folder out of nowhere

Tags: c#, nuget, command-line-interface, nuget-package

I have a .NET Framework class library project that I'm turning into a nuget package and uploading to my own nuget server.

This is how the project looks:

[image]

Really simple, just a single `.cs` file with a few classes.

I'm compiling the code with `Debug` configuration and `Any CPU` platform.

Produced files are the following: `Synteco.ScriptInterpreter.dll` and a `.pdb` file with the same name

In the directory of my `.csproj` file I also have a `.nuspec` file, which looks like this:
[image]

I'm only copying the `Synteco-Icon.png` file in the `images` folder in the final `.nupkg` in order to set the icon for my nuget package.

Upon running `nuget pack` I'm getting the following output

[image]

As we can see, everything seems to be in order.

However, if we look into the produced `.nupkg` file, its contents are:

[image]

Somehow the folder `content` has been created. In the past this folder was not created at all.

I am able to push this nuget package to my server, but when I download it via Nuget Package Manager in other projects, everything from the `content` folder is being copied into the project that is trying to use that nuget package. For larger packages this becomes a real issue and unwanted files are being copied to projects.

**What is the issue and how can I stop the `content` folder from being created?**

I've tried running `nuget pack [NAME_OF_MY_NUSPEC_FILE]` but that would produce something even more strange. Take a look:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

P.S.

As far as I'm concerned, this is how a proper nuget package should look like. This is Newtonsoft.Json:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved!

Silly me, I actually had some files with build action set to `Content` in my C# project for my nuget packages!

Upon removing all items with that build action the content folder is gone!